# How to disable cookies using qtwebengine?

Tags: python, cookies, pyqt5, qtwebengine, qwebengineview

PyQt5.14 QWebEngineView How do I disable cookies? I cannot find any reference to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible option is to use QWebEngineCookieStore associated with the profile to eliminate existing cookies and establish a filter to deny new cookies.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    cookie_store = view.page().profile().cookieStore()

    def cookie_filter(request):
        print(
            f"firstPartyUrl: {request.firstPartyUrl.toString()}, origin: {request.origin.toString()}, thirdParty? {request.thirdParty}"
        )
        return False

    cookie_store.setCookieFilter(cookie_filter)
    cookie_store.deleteAllCookies()
    view.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.qt.io"))
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: A BIG thank you. I see you do freelance work? How can I reach you?

Comment: Have a small issue with this applying to my project. I am using /pythonguis/15-minute-apps/blob/master/browser_tabbed/browser_tabbed.py from github as my basic start point. I added the cookie_store code to the add_new_tab function. I did change your "view" name to "browser" as used in the sample code. The cookie_filter was added just above the add_new_tab function. When I execute your code it works. When I execute my code I get Segmentation fault (core dumped) with program exited with code: 139.

Comment: @devmaster1 1) Without code I will not be able to point out anything to you, for the only time I will try to help you since you seem to be a beginner in Qt so I recommend that you do the following: Create a repo in GitHub, upload your application there and in a branch implement my solution and then tell me your repo and the branch to analyze the code and if I get the solution then I can give you a PR. 2) In a few hours I will answer your email

Comment: 1) file is at github raspi-four/tabbed-browser branch:modification  2) OK

Comment: @ eyllanesc Cookie fix is prefect! Thanks